# Returning a variable from a function in php class (return not working only echo works)

Tags: php

I have a PHP class that highlights names mentioned in a text as links.It can search for @character in a given text and check the names that follow that character.

Theproblem is that the return value from class does not get printed out when I `echo` the method (`public function process_text ($text_txt){}`) that is responsible for processing the text. But when I change the `return` language construct to `print` or `echo`, then the parsing is successful and the processed string is printed out. I need to `return` and not `print` so as to be able to store the return string in a comments table of my CMS.

Kindly see full code below and advise:

```
class mentions {
    public $print_content = '';
    private $m_names = array();
    private $m_denied_chars = array(
        "@",
        "#",
        "?",
        "¿"
    );
    private $m_link = "http://example.com/";    // + name of the username, link or whatever

    /*
     * this class can also be used for specific links
     * start editing from here
     * */

    public function add_name ($name) {
        array_push($this->m_names, $name);
    }

    public function process_text ($text_txt) {
        $expl_text = explode(" ", $text_txt);

        /*
         * a character will be ignores which can be specified next this comment
         * :)
         * */

        $sp_sign = "@"; // this is what you can change freely...

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($expl_text); ++$i) {
            $spec_w = $expl_text[$i];
            $print_link = false;
            $name_link = "";
            if ($spec_w[0] == $sp_sign) {   // then can be a mention...
                $name = "";
                $break_b = false;
                for ($x = 1; $x < strlen($spec_w); ++$x) {
                    if ($spec_w[$x] == '.' || $spec_w[$x] == ",") {
                        if (in_array($name, $this->m_names)) {
                            $print_link = true;
                            $name_link = $name;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (in_array($spec_w[$x], $this->m_denied_chars)) {
                        $break_b = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    $name .= $spec_w[$x];
                }
                if ($break_b == true) {
                    $print_link = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (in_array($name, $this->m_names)) {
                        $print_link = true;
                        $name_link = $name;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($print_link == true) {
                $this->print_content = "<a href=\"".$this->m_link."".$name_link."\">".$spec_w."</a>";
                if ($i < count($expl_text)) $this->print_content .=  " ";

            } else {
                $this->print_content =  $spec_w;
                if ($i < count($expl_text)) $this->print_content .=  " ";
            }
            return $this->print_content;
        }
    }
}
###### create new class object and process raw data ######
$mentions = new mentions;
$raw_data = 'Hello, @Angelina. I am @Bob_Marley.';

$expr = '#(?:^|\W)@([\w-]+)#i';
preg_match_all($expr, $raw_data, $results);
if( !empty($results[1]) ) {

    foreach( $results[1] as $user ) {
        $mentions->add_name($user);
    }
    /*
    ------------------------------------
    */
     $commenData = $mentions->process_text($raw_data);
     echo $commenData;
}
```

Comment: could you var_dump the '$mentions' variable ?

Comment: Could you post the desired output?

Comment: @Terminus, the desired output is simply `Hello, @Angelina. I am @Bob_Marley` the (at )mention strings are hyperlinked in the output.

Comment: @Sunitrams' this is the var_dump of the $mentions variable: `object(mentions)[1]
  public 'print_content' => string 'Hello, ' (length=7)
  private 'm_names' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Angelina' (length=8)
      1 => string 'Bob_Marley' (length=10)
  private 'm_denied_chars' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '@' (length=1)
      1 => string '#' (length=1)
      2 => string '?' (length=1)
      3 => string '¿' (length=1)
  private 'm_link' => string 'http://example.com/' (length=19)`

Comment: I was able to resolve this, but I do not have an explanation for this and would appreciate some explanation. <br/> Step 1: Change the return value from string to array. <br/> Step 2: Move the return value out of the **FOR LOOP**<br/> Step 3: Return the array.

Comment: If you have a return inside of a loop, the loop (and the entire function) will be interrupted and the value being returned will immediately be returned. That's just how it works. Was trying to write that as a good answer but couldn't. Did end up rewriting your class a bit. http://ideone.com/vaV0d2 note that i left in a test var_dump and that the output provided by ideone doesn't allow link tags to be displayed as html but if you run it from a server, it'll be correct

Answer (score 0):

answer by @Terminus. If you have a return inside of a loop, the loop (and the entire function) will be interrupted and the value being returned will immediately be returned. That's just how it works. Was trying to write that as a good answer but couldn't. Did end up rewriting your class a bit. ideone.com/vaV0d2 note that i left in a test var_dump and that the output provided by ideone doesn't allow link tags to be displayed as html but if you run it from a server, it'll be correct